# XML parsing in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xml

```
NSString * myxml=@"<ticketRequestOut>
  <ticketsCount>2</ticketsCount>
  <tickets>
    <ticket>
      <ticketData>006Cbm5ubm53bm53bndub</ticketData>
      <ticketId>6</ticketId>
    </ticket>
    <ticket>
      <ticketData>00BCbndub8</ticketData>
      <ticketId>7</ticketId>
    </ticket>
  </tickets>
</ticketRequestOut>";
```

How can I parse this string in Objective-C? Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse an NSString containing XML in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924389/how-do-i-parse-an-nsstring-containing-xml-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 2):

Your string doesn't look like it contains XML, but XML can be parsed in Objective-C with methods implemented by NSXMLParser.

Comment: Yeah, that looks like random ascii.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSXML_Concepts/Articles/TraversingTree.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001257).