# Objective C, How to parse this XML?

Tags: objective-c, xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <methodResponse>
   <params>
     <param>
       <value>
         <struct>
             <member><name>topic_id</name><value><string>3</string></value></member>
             <member><name>topic_title</name><value><string>Asdf</string></value></member>
             <member><name>topic_slug</name><value><string>asdf</string></value></member>
           </struct>
       </value>
     </param>
   </params>
 </methodResponse>
```

What is the best way to parse this XML?
I have used NSParser but this XML looks different. I don't know how to part the structure part in XML

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse an NSString containing XML in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924389/how-do-i-parse-an-nsstring-containing-xml-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You easily can use **touch xml** that support `XPATH` (http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/).

Xpath permits to get data in this way: `@"//member"`, To get all members without know the xml structure!

Download from here: http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Developer-Tools/TouchXML.shtml

hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I downloaded touch XML but don't know how to use it. I was looking for a tutorial how to use the touch xml but couldn't finde one. Could you explain a little bit more how I can actually use it?

Comment: @LCYSoft use this: http://dblog.com.au/general/iphone-sdk-tutorial-building-an-advanced-rss-reader-using-touchxml-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to do with this XML information. If you're targeting the iOS Plattform, Apple encourages you to do the XML parsing inline, means that you should not keep complete dom trees in memory.

If you would like to work with a DOM tree after your parsing you sure can use e.g. touchXML or we worked with KissXML (http://code.google.com/p/kissxml/) which became pretty handy for us.