# Parsing XML in Objective-C. Retrieve a specific value

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, xml-parsing

I have the following string in XML:

```
<Data>
    <Table>
        <Id>44</Id>
        <Name>My Name</Name>
        <Category>My Category</Category>
    </Table>
</Data>
```

This is contained within an NSString.  I want the quickest way to get the Category into an NSString.  I've looked at using NSXMLParser.  And I also looked at XMLReader.

Comment: I use NSXMLParser. It works fairly well

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C, How to parse this XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203359/objective-c-how-to-parse-this-xml) among [many others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxml%5D+%5Bobjective-c%5Dparsing).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse an NSString containing XML in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924389/how-do-i-parse-an-nsstring-containing-xml-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I like using XMLReader.

```
NSDictionary *dic = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:xmlString error:nil];

category = [dic valueForKeyPath:@"Data.Table.Category.text"];
```

Seems pretty clean and simple to me.