# XML parsing library in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xml, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I parse an NSString containing XML in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924389/how-do-i-parse-an-nsstring-containing-xml-in-objective-c)

Is there a class library like .net's XMLDocument in objective-c ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're on the Mac, NSXMLDocument is is probably you're looking for.

If you're on iOS however most of the NSXML* classes aren't included. [TouchXML](https://github.com/mrevilme/TouchXML) shares most of the same interface with the NSXML classes and is meant to act as a replacement for them on iOS. I've had good luck with it in the past.

Comment: I've used TouchJSON and it has never let me down. If you can use JSON instead of XML you may find there is a performance advantage in some cases. I find it easier to work with JSON as it eliminates headaches with namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html)  to parse XML Documents in objective-c.